# Loading 5 million records from server A to Server B using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I'm new to SSIS,  I need to your suggestion, I have created SSIS package which retrieve data from source server around 5 million records from server A and save data into destination server. in  this process it is taking nearly 3 hours to complete the task. can we have any other way to reduce the timeline. I have tried to increase the buffer size, but still same.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are many factors influencing the speed of execution. both hardware and software. Based on the structure of the database, a solution can be determined.

In a test project, I have transferred 40 million records in 30 minutes on a system with 4 GB of RAM.